# Подскажите как сверстать элемент

Tags: css3, html5, адаптивная-верстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю как сверстать форму и расположить ее над картой, прошу помогите, заранее благодарен

Comment: Что вы уже сверстали и что у вас не получается?

Comment: сверстал форму и установил кату пытаюсь форму над картой поставить выходит не тот результат как на картинке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема: проблема как я понимаю у вас в правильном расположении элементов. Из-за чего один другого перекрывает, тут решение довольно простое, дать `z-index`, то есть порядок отображения элементов. У карты и формы должен быть общий контейнер, это нужно для того чтобы форма всегда располагалась по центру карты, с учетом того, что карта растянута на всю ширину контейнера:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relative;
}
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://images.indianexpress.com/2017/05/google-maps-759.jpg);
  z-index: 0;
}
.form {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.form input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="map"></div>
  <form action="#" method="POST" class="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <button type="#">Кнопка</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое вы меня выручили, будь таким милосердным подскажи как делать карты на google maps ?

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как правильный, чтобы он помог другим =)

Comment: так уже отметил залип на ваш лаконичный код

Comment: на счет того как добавить карту почитайте к примеру вот https://nubex.ru/blog/seryozha_siroezhkin/google_map/ И ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО ЧИТАЙТЕ ОФЕЦИАЛЬНУЮ ДОКУМЕНТАЦИИ google map

Comment: спасибо ВАМ БОЛЬШОЕ

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте свою форму в div с картой, и пропишите стили для формы

```
`position: relative;
 top: 100px;
 left: 150px;
 opacity: 0.7;
 border-radius: 40px;`
```